# How use main json objects to make additional json request

Tags: javascript, html, json

I’m trying to create vehicles arrival timing based on nearby stops

stops.json

```
{
  "stops": [{
    "name": "Big Park",
    "code": "BP",
    "lat": 38.7273,
    "lng": 287.83838
  },
{
    "name": "Small Park",
    "code": "SP",
    "lat": 63.8373,
    "lng": 227.73689
  }]
}
```

If the stop “Small Park” is near me, domain.com/?name=Small%20Park request will be made to get the arrvial timings of Small Park.

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "nextarr": "5",
            "subarr": "10",
            "code": "SP",
        },
        {
            "nextarr": "6",
            "subarr": "12",
            "code": "SP",
        }
    ]
}
```

Show Nearby (HTML)

```
<div class="nearby">
   <div class"card"> 
     <p>Small Park</p>
     <p>5</p>
     <p>10</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, sounds like something one might do - what is the issue? Which part can't you do? (note: your data structure is not valid at all)

Comment: I managed to get all the nearby stops appeared if nearby. But I need to use the name of the stops to get the arrival timings by requesting to domain.com/?name=Small%20Park. domain.com/?name=(stopname) will give me the arrival timing for that stop. So if multiple stops near me I need to request multiple  times to get the arrival timings for each stops

Comment: yes, that's right - so where do you get `Small Park` based on the invalid structure you've presented in the question?

Comment: Small Park comes from a json file that I already had. Inside contains the lng and lat which I will use to see if I’m near to that coordinates.

Comment: But how does that relate to `Small Park Stop`??? do you just find the nearby stops and remove `' Stop'` from the `.name` to use in the request to `domain.com`

Comment: So if small park and big park is near me. I need to request to url.com?name=(stopname) to get another json data for the arrival timings. All these will be requested simultaneously and display to the dom

Comment: My bad, there’s no ' Stop'. Only its name.

Comment: your stops.json is still not valid json

Comment: Thanks. Removed additional commas. Should be valid now..

Comment: You'd think so, except it still isn't ... is `stops` supposed to be an array perhaps?

Comment: Yes, You’re right!

Answer (score 0):

```
initArgs = window.location.search.slice(1)
                    .split('&')
                    .reduce(function _reduce(/*Object*/ a, /*String*/ b) {
                        b = b.split('=');
                        a[b[0]] = decodeURIComponent(b[1]);
                        return a;
                    }, {});


function get_values({ name }) {
    stops.forEach( i => {
        if (i["name"] == name) {
            // do something
        }
    })
}

get_values(initArgs);
```

This is about as far as I can get you with writing your app for you. I'm not sure exactly how you plan to get get the second set of data once the url argument is parsed and checked against your initial data structure.